# SQL query to replace string based on wildcardt

Tags: mysql, wordpress, replace, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I would like to run this type of query on my WP database to remove all span instances with id="more-":

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (
post_content,
'<p><span id="more-35075"></span></p>',
'');
```

But the number that follows the 'more-' in my example is a variable. How to write this query with someting like a wildcard: span id="more-*.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using MySQL server version 8.0 and above ?

Comment: A better question imo is why you're storing html in a database vs storing just the id and the post content. Then you can use your application to format the HTML

Comment: Manipulating HTML with MySQL may work in extremely trivial cases, but anything even remotely complex is basically impossible without a proper HTML parser.

Comment: @Rogue he is not storing. Wordpress is storing it (table name is `wp_posts`); most likely OP has no control over it.

Comment: Surely whatever wordpress plugin he is using has some way of being manipulated to not do ... well awful things?

Comment: Thanks all! @MadhurBhaiya The server version is 10.0.36.

Comment: @APEWAW you are using MariaDB then

Comment: @APEWAW will you have multiple `'<p><span id="more-35075"></span></p>'` inside a field ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yes, it's MariaDB. There is only one '<p><span id="more-"></span></p>' inside a field. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL version 8.0 and above, you can use [`REGEX_REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function. In [absence of the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285104/sql-query-to-remove-all-span-starting-with-more-id#comment93452742_53285104), some complicated string operations can be done. This is based on your [confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285104/sql-query-to-remove-all-span-starting-with-more-id#comment93454617_53285104), that the said sub-string is occurring only once in a value.

[`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) does not have any support for wildcards, patterns, regular expressions etc. It only replaces a given *fixed* substring with another *fixed* substring, in a bigger string.

Instead, we can try to extract portions of the `post_content`. We will extract the leading substring before the `'<p><span id="more-'` using [`Substring_Index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function. Similarly, we will extract the trailing substring after the `'"></span></p>'` portion.

Now, we can simply [`Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) these portions to get the required `post_content`. You can find details of various String functions used here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html

I have also added a `WHERE` condition, so that we pick only those rows which match our given substring criteria.

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_content = 
CONCAT( 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, 
                       '<p><span id="more-', 
                       1), 
       SUBSTRING(post_content, 
                 LOCATE('"></span></p>', 
                        post_content, 
                        LOCATE('<p><span id="more-',
                               post_content)
                        ) + 13) -- 13 is character length of "></span></p>
      )
WHERE post_content LIKE '%<p><span id="more-%"></span></p>%';
```

---

**Query #1: Data before Update operations**

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts;

| post_content                                            |
| ------------------------------------------------------- |
| adasdaadsa<p><span id="more-35075"></span></p>121324124 |
| 1412123123<p><span id="more-232"></span></p>adasdaafas  |
```

---

**Query #2: Data after Update operations**

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts;

| post_content         |
| -------------------- |
| adasdaadsa121324124  |
| 1412123123adasdaafas |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2JWNM4nT9YyRrrEGAyokoY/1)

Comment: Hello Madhur. Thank you for your help! I launched the SQL query but I get the message: 0 rows affected.

Comment: @APEWAW can you setup a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ 
Also check the DB fiddle links I have shared. Maybe there is something different in your sample data.

Comment: My fault! There were not always <p> tags, so I adapted the query and it worked perfectly. A big thank you for your very valuable help!