# Replace template smart tags <<tag>> to [tag] in mysql

Tags: mysql, replace

I have an table name templateType, It has column name Template_Text.
The Template have many smart tags <> to [tag] using mysql, and I need to replace << to [ and >> with ].

**Edit from OP's comments:**

It is an template with large text and having multiple smart tags. As example : `" I <<Fname>> <<Lname>>, <<UserId>> <<Designation>> of xyz organization, Proud to announce...."`

Here I need to replace these << with [ and >> with ], so it will look like

```
" [Fname] [Lname], [UserId] ...."
```

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, It is an template with large text and having multiple smart tags. As example : " I <<Fname>> <<Lname>>, <<UserId>> <<Designation>> of xyz organization, Proud to announce...."
Here I need to replace these  << with [ and >> with ], so it will look like " [Fname] [Lname], [UserId] ...."

Comment: Also, what is your MySQL server version ? If you have the latest version (8.0 and above), you can use [`Regex_Replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function.

Comment: If the version is older, you may check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53286571/2469308

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes I have older version of mysql, that example was good, but it was for single value only, I am having multiple smart tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, your MySQL version does not support [`Regex_Replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function. So, a generic solution is not feasible.

Assuming that your string does not contain additional `<<` and `>>`, other than following the `<<%>>` format, we can use [`Replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function.

I have also added a `WHERE` condition, so that we pick only those rows which match our given substring criteria.

```
Update templateType
SET Template_Text = REPLACE(REPLACE(Template_Text, '<<', '['), '>>', ']')
WHERE Template_Text LIKE '%<<%>>%'
```

In case the problem is further complex, you may get some ideas from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53286571/2469308

Answer (score 0):

A couple of [`replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) calls should work:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(template_text, '<<', '['), '>>', '])
FROM   template_type
```