# MY SQL Query for remove all a tags from field

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a WordPress website, which was under malware attack recently. I manage to remove all malware files and ad security.

But that hacker injected some random urls like below to end of all post contents. site have around 1.5k posts.

```
<a href="http://www.cgparkaoutlet.com">canada goose outlet</a>  <a href="http://www.cgparkaoutlet.com">canada goose outlet</a>
```

[image]

I need to remove this these links. already tested this mysql but it's not working

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, substring_index( substring_index(post_content, 'href="', -1),  '"', 1),'');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<a href="">','');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content= REPLACE(post_content, '<a href="" target="_blank">','');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content= REPLACE(post_content, '</a>','');
```

anyone know how to remove those links from all posts without aging contents. Thank You

Comment: You can do `htmlentities()` to the content posted. So, the JS won't execute.

Comment: There will not be any other non-malicious `<a href=......</a>` in your `post_content` column ?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53286571/2469308 you may get some ideas from it.

Comment: Don't do parsing/replacing with mysql. It is very limited. Select the data from the db in PHP, run a function over it to remove the malicious data, then update the records.

Comment: yes there have non malicious a tags like <a><img src="test.jpg"/></a> , i want to keep those too, the only advantage is these injected links are in end of the contents

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you , use wp_strip_all_tags wordpress function for example :

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query("update `wp_posts` set post_content = ".wp_strip_all_tags( $string ) ....);
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_strip_all_tags

Comment: actually i cannot strip all tags becoz there have image tags too, there also have image tags warped by a tags those also need to keep, it seems  bit hard task

Comment: this function has two parameter for $remove_breaks Please see document..https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp